# How can I programmatically remove tagged cells without scrolling to them?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

I've learned a rather succinct way to delete tagged cells using `NotebookLocate`, but I would prefer the notebook did not scroll to the selection just for a delete operation. How can I delete tagged cells without the notebook scrolling?

Minimal example:

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[x^2, CellTags -> "oldcell"]];

Button["Remove old cell", {
  NotebookLocate["oldcell"];
  NotebookDelete[];
}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Button["Remove old cell",
NotebookFind[InputNotebook[], "oldcell",All, CellTags, AutoScroll -> False];
NotebookDelete[]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to use [`Cells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cells) to find the cells instead of [`NotebookFind`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookFind):

```
Button[
    "Remove old cell",
    NotebookDelete @ Cells[CellTags -> "oldcell"]
]
```